# Unable to load library from custom paths during compilation

Tags: gcc, compilation, linker, dynamic-linking, qnx

I am working on cross compiling my code base for `QNX aarch64` architecture on x86_64 host.

The gcc version i am using is 12.2 where it expects minimum glib version as `2.25` as per error :-

```
lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx8.0.0/12.2.0/cc1:  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx8.0.0/12.2.0/cc1)
```

`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` => is basically with version `2.23`

So i have to workaround this by loading glibc (libc.so) and other libraries from my custom path where i have required version of `libc.so.6` with version `2.36`. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47115598/21578724) answer useful and try to load the libraries accordingly and here is my compilation command :-

```
/home/unix-build/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /home/unix-build/lib64 /home/usr/bin/qcc -V12.2.0,gcc_ntoaarch64le -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -DSTD_NOWINSOCK2 -DRELEASE -DNDEBUG  -o threadsMessageDefs.o -c /llvm/repo/../../utilities/threads/threadsMessageDefs.c
```

`/home/unix-build/lib64` => contains all required libraries that satisfices including libc.so.6 (`2.36` version).

Some reason libraries are not getting loading from `/home/unix-build/lib64`. I still face the same issue where `lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx8.0.0/12.2.0/cc1` is referring to  system path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`

Do i need to follow different approach for QNX?
Am i missing something? Please advice.

Comment: Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 => is basically with version 2.23

There is no *basically* here -- either it's 2.23 or it isn't.

> So i have to workaround this by loading glibc (libc.so) and other libraries from my custom path

You don't *have to*, you are *choosing* to.

The correct solution is to either

- rebuild `gcc-12.2` *on your system*, so it just works (TM), or
- if you insist on using pre-built `gcc-12.2`, upgrade your system to be compatible with it (i.e. upgrade to something using GLIBC-2.25 or above).

> I still face the same issue where lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx8.0.0/12.2.0/cc1 is referring to system path /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

You are facing the same issue because the command you used affects `qcc` (the frontend) and *only* `qcc`. It does not affect any subprocesses `qcc` creates (the `cc1` here).